# Catch exception thrown by setter of entity

Tags: java, spring, exception

I am trying to catch the exception thrown by entity setter.

Lets say i have class Player, and want to save his progress and have

```
private float progess
```

and i want to have it between 0 and 1. I have setter

```
public void setProgress(float progress){
  if( progress < 0.0f || progress > 1.0f ) throw new IllegalArgumentException("progress parameter has to be between 0.0 and 0.1");
  this.progress = progress;
}
```

Where should i catch this exception?  I am trying it using

```
   try{
    playerDao.save(player)
   }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
    ... 
   }
```

But this does not catch it. Where or how can i catch it so i can logg it and so on? Thanks for help.

Comment: You should not catch such an exception. It's a bug. So if it's thrown, you should fix the code that tries passing an invalid argument. That said, **if** it was a good idea to catch it, the try block should contain the call to the setter. playerDao.save(player) doesn't call that setter method, so the exception isn't thrown, and thus can't be caught.

Comment: But what if this was some kind of rest API? And user would  post progress more than 1.0 or less than 0.0, how should i handle it then<

Comment: If it is an external API you don't want to throw IllegalArgumentException. Validate the arguments in the API and return something suitable or throw a specific exception of some sort that you or the framework you are using can catch and convert to something useful. And you can only catch exceptions that are thrown in a try block. Your try block does not include a call to setProgress so the exception is not thrown there and cannot be caught.

Answer (score 0):

The setter method has to be wrapped in your try-catch block in order for the exception to be thrown / caught. For example:

```
float progress = 2F; // example to throw the exception

try 
    setProgress(progress);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // if you're here, progress < 0 or progress > 1
    // TODO handle the exception
}
```

That said, what is the use case for this? It would be much better to refactor your code such that the `setProgress` method can only receive a valid argument. For example:

```
float progress = 2F;

if (isValid(progress)) {
    setProgress(progress);
} else {
    // TODO show the user a message, etc.
}

...

private void isValid(float progress) {
    return (progress >= 0F && progress <= 1F);
}

private void setProgress(float progress) {
    this.progress = progress;
}
```